# Can Map operations be compiled or otherwise sped up for large lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, compile, map

I'm performing a series of `Map` operations in the following script:

```
inputList = Table[RandomReal[100, {60, 2}], {i, 1, 10^3}];
scalingFactor = 10;
i = 1;
listX = Round[scalingFactor*Table[{inputList[[i, k]], # - inputList[[i, k]] & /@ inputList[[i]]}, {k, 1, Length[inputList[[i]]]}]];
i = 2;
listY = Round[scalingFactor*Table[{inputList[[i, k]], # - inputList[[i, k]] & /@ inputList[[i]]}, {k, 1, Length[inputList[[i]]]}]];

selectedIndices = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {10^3, 2}];
pairList = {listX[[#[[1]], 1]], listY[[#[[2]], 1]]} & /@ selectedIndices;
```

The above code is mostly meant to illustrate the kind of `Map` operations I'm doing, however, a description of what's going on would be as follows:

(1) We first generate `inputList`, which, at the outermost level, contains $10^3$ lists, each with $60$ pairs of real numbers (the pairs are of the form: `{RandomReal[{0,100}],RandomReal[{0,100}]}`).

(2) `listX` and `listY`, computed in precisely the same way but for different lists in `inputList` (with indices $i = 1$ and $2$, respectively), generate $60$ two-element lists (one for each point in `inputList[[i]]`) that look like this:

```
listXexample = {{{440, 663}, {{0, 0}, {467, 333}, {376, -548}, {-178, -128}, {-254, -560}, {262, -533}, {-203, 202}, {63, -68}, {160, -604}, {382, -187}, {471, -162}, {-292, 336}, {-317, -196}, {-75, 253}, {-199, -125}, {-214, -543}, {246, -456}, {363, -455}, {-366, 235}, {-178, 309}, {211, 255}, {27, -360}, {495, -458}, {-34, -452}, <<12>>, {-259, -133}, {-232, 103}, {-375, -387}, {-98, -455}, {253, -548}, {233, -418}, {207, 245}, {367, -100}, {107, 19}, {419, -85}, {324, -526}, {465, -434}, {-342, -506}, {216, 35}, {452, 254}, {-252, 215}, {307, -110}, {-344, 277}, {387, -449}, {-62, -542}, {140, -78}, {-249, -49}, {-66, -425}, {-251, 175}}}, <<58>>, {<<1>>, {<<1>>}}};
```

The first element in each list, e.g. `{440, 663}` as above, represents a chosen element, and the second element represents a list of the differences between this chosen element and all other elements in inputList[[i]], e.g. `# - {440, 663}` in the above example.  All values in these lists are then rounded, as shown.

(3) `pairList` is computed by taking a (here random) set of integer indices of the form `{{20,40},{40,15},...}`, and then performing the mapping operation:

```
pairList = {listX[[#[[1]], 1]], listY[[#[[2]], 1]]} & /@ selectedIndices;
```

Where we `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]` represents the first and second element, respectively, in a particular integer pair in `selectedIndices`.

To simulate the script inputs, we're using the following randomly generated test values:

```
scalingFactor = 10;
inputList = Table[RandomReal[100, {60, 2}], {i, 1, 10^3}];
selectedIndices = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {10^3, 2}];
```

As well as the $i = (1,2)$ values.

---

---

---

Is there a way to compile and speed up the sort of `Map` operations above?

---

Also, can anyone replicate my finding that changing:

```
inputList = Table[RandomReal[100, {50, 2}], {i, 1, 10^3}];
```

To:

```
inputList = Table[RandomReal[100, {100, 2}], {i, 1, 10^3}];
```

Counterintuitively halves the effective time to compute:

```
pairList = {listX[[#[[1]], 1]], listY[[#[[2]], 1]]} & /@ selectedIndices
```

Why would this happen?

---

---

---

Update:  Running Mr. Wizard's reformulated code:

```
inputList = RandomReal[100, {1000, 60, 2}];
selectedIndices = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {10^3, 2}];
scalingFactor = 10;

t1 = AbsoluteTime[];

i = 1;
listX = Round[scalingFactor*Table[{inputList[[i, k]], # - inputList[[i, k]] & /@ inputList[[i]]}, {k, 1, Length[inputList[[i]]]}]];
i = 2;
listY = Round[scalingFactor*Table[{inputList[[i, k]], # - inputList[[i, k]] & /@ inputList[[i]]}, {k, 1, Length[inputList[[i]]]}]];

myPairList = {listX[[#[[1]], 1]], listY[[#[[2]], 1]]} & /@ selectedIndices;



t2 = AbsoluteTime[];

f1[m_] := With[{t = m\[Transpose]}, {m, Subtract[t, #]\[Transpose] & /@ m}\[Transpose]]

{listX, listY} = Round[scalingFactor * f1 /@ inputList[[{1, 2}]]];

pairList = {listX[[#, 1]], listY[[#2, 1]]}\[Transpose] & @@ (selectedIndices\[Transpose])


t3 = AbsoluteTime[];


myPairList == pairList
```

Outputs `True`.

We can also note that the timing for my code vs. Mr. Wizard's

```
myTiming = t2 - t1
mrWizardTiming = t3 - t2
```

Is about $\approx 65$ milliseconds (me) and $\approx 3$ milliseconds (Mr. Wizard), respectively.  Nicely done Mr. Wizard!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a written description of your operation in addition to the code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Absolutely Mr. Wizard.

Comment: You are using only the first part of each sublist in `listX` or `listY`, meaning that none of the difference data ends up in `pairList`.  Shall I assume this is correct, and that `listX` and `listY` must be generated as shown for use elsewhere?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's correct - this is a representative snippet from a larger piece of code, I just wanted to accurately portray the data structures I'm using.

Comment: Please see my answer and try it on your larger data set.  I could not replicate the final example in your question, but I am using version 7 and things may have changed.

Comment: By the way, you may find timings inaccurate in the millisecond range.  I suggest using `timeAvg` (search the site) or larger data sets to get a better feel for actual performance.

Comment: `Map` autocompiles lists (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-you-determine-the-optimal-autocompilation-length-on-your-system) when possible so speed ups are likely to come from other code improvements as per @Mr.Wizard code rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my refactoring of your code:

```
inputList       = RandomReal[100, {1000, 60, 2}];
selectedIndices = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {10^3, 2}];
scalingFactor   = 10;

f1[m_] := With[{t = m\[Transpose]}, {#, Subtract[t, #]\[Transpose]} & /@ m]

{listX, listY} = Round[scalingFactor * f1 /@ inputList[[{1, 2}]]];

pairList = {listX[[#, 1]], listY[[#2, 1]]}\[Transpose] & @@ (selectedIndices\[Transpose])
```

---

My basic approach was to shift processing into vector/array operations on larger chunks of data.  To that end I used `Transpose` to allow pairwise subtraction from the entire block (i.e. `inputList[[1]]`) at once.  This means that there is essentially one loop in place of two at least in terms of high level constructs.  Here is a self-contained example:

```
s1 = Partition[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 2] ~Take~ 6;

Table[j - i, {i, s1}, {j, s1}]

Table[(s1\[Transpose] - i)\[Transpose], {i, s1}]
```

I used `Table` instead of `Map` for both to emphasize the difference.  Note that this is somewhat wasteful as `s1` is repeatedly transposed; I used `With` in my `f1` function to prevent this.

Likewise for `pairList` I transposed `selectedIndices` to get two vectors, positions to extract from each `listX` and `listY` and passed them using `Apply` and `Function`.  This removes a top-level loop (`Map`) completely and lets vector-optimized `Part` work efficiently.  I then use a second `Transpose` to reshape the data as desired.

Comment: I updated my question comparing the result of my code with yours and I noticed a discrepancy?  I apologize - it was a bit too long to do that in comment form.  Let me know if I'm messing something up on my end.

Comment: @RM1618 Adding such things to the question is the correct way.  Let me take a look at it.

Comment: @RM1618 You somehow lost both `\[Transpose]` symbols in my `pairList` line, but correctly preserved them in the `f1` definition.  If you add those two the results should match.

Comment: Got it, and you achieved a speedup of over an order of magnitude!  If you feel like it, could you offer some pointers about why this is so much faster?

Comment: @RM1618 Thanks for the vote, but you might wait longer to Accept; someone else may give you a better solution if you do not discourage looking at the question.  I'll add a few comments to my answer for explanation.

Comment: Ok, I'll do so, but thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the description, that's very helpful.

Comment: Can f1 be compiled?  Would this help?

Comment: @RM1618 I think there would be some complication with that because the result is not a rectangular array.  Also, I wouldn't expect to gain much with an operation such as this.  Nevertheless I'll try it and see.

Comment: It's already very fast - I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @RM1618 I got about a 12% speed-up with my attempt at compilation.  I don't think that is worth the loss of generality, but I can post it, or try harder to optimize it, if this is going to make a difference to you.  Also, I noticed that I had one more `Transpose` than was productive in my `f1` function so I am going to edit my answer to replace it.